# Understanding the Translation Model using Grid LSTM cells

Tags: tensorflow, grid, translation, lstm

In the paper “[Grid Long Short-Term Memory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.01526.pdf)” the authors describe a translation model (section 4.4). My first impression was that this model was considered a 3-D Grid LSTM model, because it consisted of two 2-D Grids stacked on top of each other, i.e. two layers. Then, I read this: “The 3-LSTM uses two two-dimensional grids of 3-LSTM blocks for the hierarchy” and "Note that the second grid receives an input coming from the grid below at each 3-LSTM block". Does this mean that the 2-D grids, consists of 3-Dimensional LSTMs? In the introduction, they say that N-LSTM is a shorter notation for N-dimensional Grid LSTM.

This is a figure of their model:

[image]

But I'm wondering if the next figure may represent the model better based on the information above (just with fewer layers):
[image]

I'm using Tensorflow, and I have used the MultiRNNCell to stack two Grid2LSTMCells on top of each other. But now I'm thinking that I should rather use the Grid3LSTMCell.. Any comments or thoughts? :)